# React Native - How do I find if one of the values in an array matches one of the values in the other array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, if-statement, react-native

I have found and tried out `.includes` to help with this problem. But `.includes` did not work as I intended. It actually did find which value in the array match the value in the other array, but it only matched **similar values**:

**result_postid results mapped with commas**:

```
[10,22,12,36,45,206]
```

**item.id results mapped with commas**:

```
[5,13,28,136,400,538]
```

I tried to figure out why some of the values kept returning `true` when they should be clearly `false`. Then I came to the conclusion that `.includes` was actually taking **`36`** from `result_postid` and matching it with **`136`** in `item.id`. This is how I setup the if statement with `.includes`:

```
{result_postid.includes(item.id) ?
 <Text>True</Text>
 :
 <Text>False</Text>
}
```

This is the result:

```
result_postid | item.id | Result

10 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
22 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
12 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
36 =  5,13,28,136,400,538: True <--- this should be false
45 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
206 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
```

Is it possible to find if one of the values in the array exactly matches one of values in the other array?

This is what my result_postid looks like before I `map` it :

```
render() {

const result_postid = this.state.data_one.map(function(val) {
 return val.postid;
}).join(',');
}

[{"spaceid":"16","postid":"10"},{"spaceid":"16","postid":"22"},{"spaceid":"16","postid":"12"},{"spaceid":"16","postid":"36"},{"spaceid":"16","postid":"45"},{"spaceid":"16","postid":"206"}]
```

Comment: So, It's not clear to me if your result_postid was an array... but you can try to find any values with lodash.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#find

Comment: Are you sure result.postid is an array? The String class also has a method called includes().

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `.some` and `.findIndex` to achieve the same

```js
const postId = [10,22,12,36,45,206]
const itemId = [5,13,28,136,400,538]
const res = postId.some(id => itemId.findIndex(elem => elem === id) > -1);
console.log(res)
```

for rendering pupose

```js
render() {
   const isPresent = result_postid.some(id => item_id.findIndex(elem => elem === id) > -1);
   return (
      <View>
          {isPresent? <Text>True</Text>:<Text>False</Text>}
      </View>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I go about setting this up in an if and else statement in the `render()`? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @LaneyWilliams Updated it in answer

Comment: Ok Since my `item.id` is in a flatlist, I did something like this:

Comment: `{result_postid.some(id => item.id.findIndex(elem => elem === id) > -1) ? <Text>True</Text>:<Text>False</Text>}`  and I got this error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'result_postid.some')`

Comment: do I need to put it in the const?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams, can you make sure that result_postid is an array and not undefined, it its undefined, you need to provide a check for it

Comment: Yes, I updated my question above to show what the json array looked like before I used the `map`. Also, I reinserted my odd code and only got undefined when I use `.some` @ShubhamKhatri